# Writing a regular expression for nutch's regex-urlfilter.txt file

Tags: regex, nutch

I'm having some problems with regex-urlfilter.txt file.
I want to crawl only links that have numbers before '.html', should be easy but I can't get it right...

Here's an example:

http://www.utiltrucks.com/annonce-occasion-camion-poids-lourd/marque-renault/modele-midliner/ref-71015.html
http://www.utiltrucks.com/annonce-occasion-camion-poids-lourd/dpt-.html

I want to catch the first link.

I've tried with the following entry in regex-urlfilter:

## accept anything else

+[http://www.utiltrucks.com/annonce-occasion.+?[0-9]+.html](http://www.utiltrucks.com/annonce-occasion.+?%5b0-9%5d+.html)

I get a message:
0 records selected for fetching, exiting ...

Anybody got an idea how to pull this off?

Comment: Your regex starts with a `+` - Is that a typo? Should it be `^`?

Comment: Hmmm let me try with a ^, I think I already did but couldn't hurt to do it again :)

Comment: I get a Invalid first character: ^, I believe it must start with a + sign for nutch to read it...I maybe and probably am, wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that your url filters should also match with your seed URLs or else they will be filter out and hence nutch won't get any chance to parse them and extract the links you wanted.

For example, if your seed file contains this url http://www.utiltrucks.com/home then you should also add an entry in your regex-urlfilter file like this:

+http://www.utiltrucks.com/home

This should be also done for all pages that in the path from your seed urls to your target pages that you want to extract links from.

Answer (score 0):

you have to start your url like

```
+^(http|https)://www.example.com
```